# How to fix ErrorException in blade.php in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, relationship, laravel-blade

Need print user name using `user_id` in `File` table in my laravel application. This is relationship between `User` model and `File` Model .

File Model

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

This is blade file

```
@if($files)
    @foreach( $files as $file)
        <div>
            <div>
                <span>
                    {{ $file->user->name }} //line 16
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Controller

```
class PfilePDFController extends Controller
{
    public function getPFPDF($id){
        $files = File::where('project_id',$id)->get();
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.projectfiles',['files'=>$files]);
        return $pdf->stream('projectfiles.pdf');
    }
}
```

But got this error:

```
ErrorException in bd52d760518dfb36a05daedee198eefcb7b87914.php line 16: Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\Users\dnk\Desktop\acxian\resources\views\pdf\projectfiles.blade.php)
```

How to fix this problem?

Comment: no any idea about this matter

Comment: share you controller code where you are sending `$files` ?

Comment: Probably `user_id` is null or has an invalid user `id` and `$file->user` returns `null`. So, you are trying to get `name` from `null`.

Comment: see My updated Controllere I am going to print PDF file using blade file @user2486

Comment: Laerte is correct.....one of My user_id is 0

Comment: I put by bet on Laerte. The error is happening because for some reason your collection of files have one or more files that doesn't have a related `user`. You may fix it by doing: `{{ $file->user ? $file->user->name : '' }}` or using the null coalescent operator on php 7+: `{{ $file->user->name ?? '' }}`

Comment: I will post this as an answer for future readers, ok?

Comment: @EliasSoares Check `or` operator too. It can be really helpful in these situations. Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably `user_id` is `null` or has an invalid user `id` and `$file->user` returns `null`. So, you are trying to get name from null.

A good way to avoid this is using `or` in your code. Ex:

```
{{ $file->user->name or '-' }}
```

This will print `-` if any information in the line is `null`.